# Route all traffic (redirect-gateway) not working - OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

First of all, I know this question has been asked at least a million times.  I have tried many solutions and still can't get my VPN to work.  When I connect to my VPN my client IP changes to the VPN IP (expected).  But won't route all traffic through the VPN.  I can tell because I use OpenDNS as my home DNS server and use their `internetbadguys.com` test domain to test traffic through the VPN. 
 I am using the `push` flags in server.conf:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "remote-gateway vpn_server_ip"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 60
```

and in client.ovpn:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Also, if it helps, I am using an AWS EC2 instance to run my VPN.  I'm not sure what else to do next.  Hopefully, someone can figure this out :)

Thanks in advance!

Server and Client configs below:

Server:

```
port PORT
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.cert
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
# ROUTE CLIENT'S INTERNET ACCESS THROUGH THE SERVER
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "remote-gateway vpn_server_ip"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 60

crl-verify crl.pem
```

Client:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote MY-SERVER-IP PORT
remote MY-SERVER-HOSTNAME PORT
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
push "redirect-gateway def1"
verb 3
```

Comment: Whats the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` after connecting? You may need to use a script to rewrite DNS settings.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else with this problem, you most likely need to enable IP forwarding on the server as that will probably be off by default.

Put this in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And then run:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Now that takes care of your IP forwarding. If you're running a firewall (perhaps iptables) then you're probably going to want to get your NAT going so run this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Put something like this into /etc/sysconfig/iptables to make it permanent:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

All going well your server is now forwarding your client VPN traffic. The next thing you're going to want to do is head your client browser over to `whatismyipaddress.com` to see that it's showing an Amazon address and then onto `www.dnsleaktest.com` and see how things are looking. If you're leaking out through Google you may want to consider running up a simple DNS caching server on your VPN server and point your client at that if anonymity is desired.

I hope that helps.